# How to authenticate the API key in google cloud speech to text API in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-speech

Please help me about how to authenticate in easy way in google using api key only not the json file please :( help me

Comment: http://androidkt.com/speech-api/ Have You Refer This?

Comment: i will try sir thank you